# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-'

Tags: php, php-5.3

I change `ereg to preg_match` for update mycode to PHP5.3 .  now i see this warning in my page. how to fix this ?

warning :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-' in C:\xampp\htdocs\share\configs\functions.php on line 2645
```

old Code :

```
if (!ereg ("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})", $dateOfBirth, $regs))
```

New Code (PHP 5.3):

```
if (!preg_match ("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})", $dateOfBirth, $regs))
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_match_all() \[function.preg-match-all\]: Unknown modifier '\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396557/preg-match-all-function-preg-match-all-unknown-modifier) and many others, have a look at the "Related" list on the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
if (!preg_match ("/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})/", $dateOfBirth, $regs))
#                 ^                                    ^
```